# MongoDb C# driver in VB.net - sort by descending order

Tags: c#, mongodb, vb.net, sorting

I'm using the official C# driver in my VB.net application. I am trying to get the last 10 rows of a collection. Having tried multiple methods and not able to get the correct syntax to sort the collection list in descending order so that I can read the last 10 rows. This is my code...

```
     Dim collection As IMongoCollection(Of BsonDocument) = database_name.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("sys_rawdata")
        Dim Filter = New BsonDocument()
        For Each item2 As BsonDocument In collection.Find(Filter).Limit(10).ToList
            Dim timestamp As BsonElement = item2.GetElement("timestamp")
            Dim hostname As BsonElement = item2.GetElement("hostname")
            Dim objItem As ListViewItem
            objItem = lv1.Items.Add(hostname.Value.ToString)
            With objItem
                .SubItems.Add(timestamp.Value.ToString)
            End With
        Next
```

The above code gets me the first 10 rows in the collection. Then I tried many ways to sort by descending order like below..But unable to get the right syntax

Can anyone please help in giving the right syntax for the sorting in the Descending order.

```
For Each item2 As BsonDocument In collection.Find(Filter).Sort(Builders.Sort.Descending("timestamp")).ToList
```

Unable to get the right syntax in VB.net. Unfortunately this project was started in VB.net and migrating now in C# will be a lot of effort and time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I presume you mean .NET driver, not C# driver.

Comment: What goes wrong with your second attempt?

Comment: It does not work.. it just give syntax error. May be I am not putting the builder in right order.